# Mysql: how to use date_format

Tags: mysql

i tried to use this sql:

```
SELECT date_format(signdate , '%Y-%c-%d %h:%i:%s' ) as post_date , 
date_format(NOW(), '%Y-%c-%d %h:%i:%s' ) as post_date_gmt 
FROM `article`  where outkey = 'Y'
```

the result of post_date is null, but post_date is working.  so how can i use the funciton date_format to format signdate (ex: signdate is 1095959971)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) expects a `DATETIME` column.

You'd have to cast it:

```
DATE_FORMAT(CAST(signdate AS DATETIME), ....)
```

It would be better to have a real DATETIME field, though.

Comment: @Flesh what type is the `signdate` column?

Comment: Ahh, my mistqke. You need to use FROM_UNIXTIME instead of cast. I'm at uni and cant build an example